# How to build an AlertDialog with reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

i can't build an AlertDialog with reflection, Please help me

the my code:

```
try {
    Class dlg= AlertDialog.Builder.class;
    Method m=dlg.getDeclaredMethod("show",Context.class);
    m.invoke(dlg.newInstance(),this);
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("Error!",e.getMessage());
}
```

error outputed:

```
E/Error!: show [class android.content.Context]
```

Comment: Why are you using reflection, instead of normal programming techniques?

Answer (score -2):

Thank you,

Finished the Question.

My code:

```
    try {
        Class dlg= AlertDialog.Builder.class;
        Method m=dlg.getDeclaredMethod("show");
        Constructor ct=dlg.getConstructor(Context.class);
        m.invoke(ct.newInstance(this));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error!",e.getMessage());
    }
```